# How to collect signatures on a PDF in SharePoint worflow?

Tags: workflow, pdf, nintex, digital-signature

Using SharePoint 2013
Premises: Adobe PDF form needs to be digitally signed by multiple signers/approved.  Trying to eliminate multiple copies/multiple emails to folks when people don’t respond to task to sign. I do not have the capability for InfoPath, nor do I have control over the document itself. It has to stay PDF.
The program used solely is Nintex for SharePoint.

Workflow using: Approval

1st Phase – User downloads form, fills out, digitally signs, Saves and Adds to doc name _Last Name (to distinguish multiple requests), uploads to doc library (kicks off workflow)

2nd Phase – Workflow sends document (with signature) to 1st level approvers for Approval/Rejection (no sign req)

3rd Phase – Workflow sends document (with signature) to 2nd level approvers for Approval/Rejection & must open document (attached in notification) and digitally sign. Approver opens doc and as soon as they try to sign (SAVE AS box appears)-Document locks down to read-only and won’t let approver save to desktop with same name-
The same doc name is necessary for when re-uploading automating the overwrite of the document

End game: PDF needs to be automatically and sequentially sent to 3 Approvers, with the latest version of the form to be attached in the Task Notification Email for signature and approval.